# Python support for BFloat16 on macOS

Tags: python, macos, bloom

I'm trying to use the [bigscience/bloom](https://huggingface.co/bigscience/bloom) model on macOS for text completion. Here's the python script I'm using:

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bigscience/bloom')
inputs = tokenizer("My dog is ", return_tensors="pt")

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("bigscience/bloom", device_map="auto", 
offload_folder="offload", torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16)
output = model.generate(inputs["input_ids"].to(0), min_length=30, max_length=30, 
  do_sample=True)
print(tokenizer.decode(output[0].tolist()))
```

I've installed python3 3.9.12, and used pip3 to install accelerate, torch, and the HuggingFace transformers library.

When I run this, the `model.generate` fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/stevex/bloom/download.py", line 8, in <module>
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("bigscience/bloom", device_map="auto", offload_folder="offload", torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers-4.21.0.dev0-py3.9.egg/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py", line 446, in from_pretrained
    return model_class.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, config=config, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers-4.21.0.dev0-py3.9.egg/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 2119, in from_pretrained
    model, missing_keys, unexpected_keys, mismatched_keys, error_msgs = cls._load_pretrained_model(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers-4.21.0.dev0-py3.9.egg/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 2332, in _load_pretrained_model
    new_error_msgs, offload_index, state_dict_index = _load_state_dict_into_meta_model(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers-4.21.0.dev0-py3.9.egg/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 553, in _load_state_dict_into_meta_model
    offload_index = offload_weight(param, param_name, offload_folder, offload_index)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/accelerate/utils/offload.py", line 25, in offload_weight
    array = weight.numpy()
TypeError: Got unsupported ScalarType BFloat16
```

There's a bfloat16 python library but when I attempt to install it:

```
pip3 install bfloat16
```

This fails with errors compiling `bfloat16.cc`; many errors but here's a sample:

```
     bfloat16.cc:462:26: error: unexpected type name 'bfloat16': expected expression
                              /*alignment=*/alignof(bfloat16),
                                                    ^
      bfloat16.cc:757:43: error: a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')
                      struct TypeDescriptor<std::complex<float>>
                                                              ^~
                                                              > >
      bfloat16.cc:764:44: error: a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')
                      struct TypeDescriptor<std::complex<double>>
                                                               ^~
                                                               > >
```

I suspect it's not supported on macOS.

I'm not that familiar with Python so not sure where to go from here.  Thanks.

Comment: What errors did you get compiling bfloat16.cc?

Comment: Hey Scott - Updated the question to include some of the compile errors.